# pyqt5 отслеживание клавиш и мышки

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, события, gui

Мне нужно отслеживать нажатие клавиш и мышки по всему окну (включая все его виджеты). Для примера я написал программу:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QAbstractItemView, QMainWindow, QApplication
import sys


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(600, 400)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listWidget = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.listWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 256, 201))
        self.listWidget.setObjectName("listWidget")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.listWidget.addItem(item)
        self.list_2 = QtWidgets.QListWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.list_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(280, 10, 256, 201))
        self.list_2.setObjectName("list_2")
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        item = QtWidgets.QListWidgetItem()
        self.list_2.addItem(item)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.toolBar = QtWidgets.QToolBar(MainWindow)
        self.toolBar.setObjectName("toolBar")
        MainWindow.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.TopToolBarArea, self.toolBar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        __sortingEnabled = self.listWidget.isSortingEnabled()
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.listWidget.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй1"))
        item = self.listWidget.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий1"))
        self.listWidget.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        __sortingEnabled = self.list_2.isSortingEnabled()
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(False)
        item = self.list_2.item(0)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "первый2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(1)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "второй2"))
        item = self.list_2.item(2)
        item.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "третий2"))
        self.list_2.setSortingEnabled(__sortingEnabled)
        self.toolBar.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "toolBar"))


class MyWidget(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.installEventFilter(self)

        self.list_2.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.list_2.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)
        self.listWidget.setDragDropMode(QAbstractItemView.DragDrop)
        self.listWidget.setDefaultDropAction(Qt.MoveAction)

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print('press')

        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


def except_hook(cls, exception, traceback):
    sys.__excepthook__(cls, exception, traceback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyWidget()
    ex.show()
    sys.excepthook = except_hook

    app.exec()
    sys.exit()
```

Так вот проблема в том, что когда я привязываю метод к окну, то он не вызывается если события происходят на виджете (`Qlistwiget`).

Писать свой метод для всех виджетов слишком долго и не красиво.
Есть ли вариант как отслеживать все события окна?

Comment: А так `self.list_2.viewport().installEventFilter(self)` и `self.listWidget.viewport().installEventFilter(self)`?

Comment: Какие именно события нажатия мышки вы собираетесь отслеживать в виджете `QListWidget` ? Вам не достаточно сигналов доступных в данном виджете https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlistwidget.html#signals ?

Comment: клик мышкой(все виды), все нажатия на клавиатуру.

Comment: вообще, мне достаточно будет просто примера с кликом мышкой. Спасибо.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, клик по какому виджету у вас не получается реализовать ? Какую информацию вы хотите получить кликнув по этому виджету. И вообще вопрос еще актуален и вам нужен пример или комментариев, написанных выше вам достаточно?

Comment: я вроде описал проблему. тот пример который я привел, это всего лишь пример, я не смогу устанавливать на каждый виджет по фильтру. Еще раз повторюсь, мне нужно отслеживать клавиши по всему окну, включая все его виджеты. Если будет хороший пример этого будет вполне достаточно. по поводу информации, мне нужно привязать к нескольким клавишам по методу

Comment: Было бы здорово найти решение этой проблемы, мне это сейчас очень нужно.

Comment: стоит ли мне ждать, или искать другое решение проблемы?